# Docker restore failing

Tags: mysql, docker

New to Docker.  Trying restore a mysql database from tar.

```
sudo docker run -it -v web_db_data:/volume -v /tmp:/backup alpine \ sh -c "rm -rf /volume/* /volume/..?* /volume/.[!.]* ; tar -C /volume/ -xjf /backup/web_db_data.tar.bz2"
```

I get the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \" sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running a command that was written for multiple lines with a `\` and compressing it onto a single line. The `\` then escapes a space so your container is looking the `sh` command with a leading space. Change:

```
sudo docker run -it -v web_db_data:/volume -v /tmp:/backup alpine \ sh -c "rm -rf /volume/* /volume/..?* /volume/.[!.]* ; tar -C /volume/ -xjf /backup/web_db_data.tar.bz2"
```

to

```
sudo docker run -it -v web_db_data:/volume -v /tmp:/backup alpine sh -c "rm -rf /volume/* /volume/..?* /volume/.[!.]* ; tar -C /volume/ -xjf /backup/web_db_data.tar.bz2"
```

or leave it as multiple lines:

```
sudo docker run -it -v web_db_data:/volume -v /tmp:/backup alpine \
  sh -c "rm -rf /volume/* /volume/..?* /volume/.[!.]* ; tar -C /volume/ -xjf /backup/web_db_data.tar.bz2"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Getting one more error now: tar: can't open 'web_db_data.tar.bz2': No such file or directory.  I have the file located at: /tmp/backup

Comment: If your file is in /tmp/backup, but you've mounted /tmp, then your missing a backup directory in your path inside the container. It would be /backup/backup.

Answer (score 0):

The shell "sh" is not found in the $PATH Variable of the container, you can try to install it in the Dockerfile, or you can try bash, maybe it is installed